# Drag and Drop table object explorer into query window issue Sql Server Management Studio 18.1

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I recently installed SSMS 18.1 and I am having an issue when trying to drag and drop table names from the object explorer to the query window. For example, I am writing a query and dont want type out the table name I would drag and drop the table into the query editor and the name will be there.

This is the error I get: "An exception has been encountered. This may be caused by an extension".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Follow this feedback item for updates on the issue:

[SSMS Crash when dragging table from Object explorer into new query window](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035/suggestions/37887988)

> Microsoft SQL Server (Product Manager, Microsoft Azure) responded  ·  Jun 14, 2019
>
> Issue has been identified and a fix is being made. It will be rolled out with the next update of SSMS 18.

In the meantime, you could revert to SSMS 17.9.

Answer (score 2):

This is known issue and a very annoying error because the SSMS is freezing and not responding (even for mouse clicks OK on the error message), and we need to kill the SSMS process, in case we want to continue working. That really can ruin all ours today's work, if we not save one in a while, and no available fix for that now!

[Microsoft response](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/908035-sql-server/suggestions/37887988-ssms-crash-when-dragging-table-from-object-explore?) is: "Issue has been identified and a fix is being made. It will be rolled out with the next update of SSMS 18".

As I explain [here](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/ssms-181-bug-exception-has-been-encountered-may-caused-vitaly-bruk/), till will be fixed, you can work around:

1. just press ENTER or ESC button on the keyboard and it un-freeze;
2. save your work;
3. Reopen the query window

Answer (score -2):

This is clearly mentioned in the [known issues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017#known-issues-181) section of the [release notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/release-notes-ssms?view=sql-server-2017) for SSMS 18.1:

> Users may see an error when dragging a table object from the Object Explorer into the Query Editor. We are aware of the issue, and the fix is planned for the next release.

Its not a major issue since intellisense will offer auto-completion on your table names anyway but if you find it a major blocker you can always revert back to a previous version. SSMS 17.x can be installed side by side while you wait for SSMS 18.2 to be released.

Comment: I am curious to know why my answer has been down-voted. If anybody would be kind enough to provide clarity I would very much appreciate it.